# Footer not hiding when export to MS Word

Tags: reporting-services, ms-word, ssrs-2008, footer

I only want to display the footer (which has some texts) in the first page of my SSRS report. So I code the following in Expression to hide:

```
=IIF(Globals!PageNumber = 1, false, true)
```

However, when I export to MS Word via SSRS, I get the footer in every single page (it works perfectly fine in PDF).

This seems to be a known problem according to:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283105(v=sql.105).aspx#ReportHeadersFooters

And the document provided a workaround using "Expression with Text Runs".

I have been trying to figure out what that means and how to apply that but have been struggling for a while.

Does anyone know a work-around for this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This answer is pretty late in coming to this user, but for any others fighting with this, please see the msdn SQL Server export to Word write-up here:

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627455(v=SQL.100).aspx
```

In a nutshell, toggling states anywhere in the report is not supported.  Whatever the state of the report item is on the first page is what it'll be throughout the exported report.  With that in mind, it appears that PDF will be a better format to support with your customers.